# Why is my function not outputting anything?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am just trying to learn a bit about code.
I have this bit of code here whice is repeated quite a few times

Its probably messy code as im not a pro.

```
<td><?php if ($row["boption03"] >= 1) echo "
        <input 
        name='orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . 03 . "]' 
        id='" . $row['prod_selectname'] . 03 . "' 
        placeholder='3mg' type='number' 
        class='liq03 form-control'"?> <?php if ($row["boption03"] == 2) echo "disabled" ?>
        <?php if ($row["boption03"] >= 1) echo "/>"?>
        </td>
```

I am trying to put this in a function (because I think its better and tidier)

here is what I have so far

```
function liquidBox($boptionStrength) {
if ($row["boption$boptionStrength"] >= 1) echo "
            <input 
            name='orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "]' 
            id='" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "' 
            placeholder='$boptionStrength' type='number' 
            class='liq$boptionStrength form-control'" . (($row["boption$boptionStrength"] == 2)?'disabled':"") . "/>";
```

}

and calling it by

```
<td><?php liquidBox("00"); ?></td>
```

but it is not outputting anything.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

If I put var_dump($boptionStrength) before the "if" then I do get the output int(3) so the variable is being passed to the function - Suggested by Cid

Comment: Are you sure about the index `boption$boptionStrength` ?

Comment: Before your if statement, I would add this, as debug : `var_dump($row["boption$boptionStrength"]);`

Comment: Jules, the boption$boptionStrength should be boption## where ## is is the value of $boptionStrength    so would equal boption00 in this first row

Comment: Cid I tried that and get NULL in each row

Comment: Cid, if i try this var_dump($boptionStrength); then I get the output int(3) 

The $boptionStrength is not in the database, its the value im passing from the function call ie <?php liquidBox(03); ?>  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function liquidBox($row, $boptionStrength) {
    if ($row["boption0".$boptionStrength] == 2) {
        echo "<input name='orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "]' id='" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "' placeholder='$boptionStrength' type='number'   class='liq$boptionStrength form-control'" . " disabled />";
    } else {
        echo "<input name='orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "]' id='" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "' placeholder='$boptionStrength' type='number'   class='liq$boptionStrength form-control' />";
    }
}

<td><?php liquidBox($row, 1); ?></td>
```

Comment: Rishat, this outputs the <input> on every row so is echoing the 2nd instance. 
I do need the if inside to display the "disabled" inside the function becuase there are 3 options in this <td>   
1: unavailable (no <input> is displayed)
2: enabled (<input> is displayed)
3: disabled.(<input> is shown in disabled state)

Comment: You can change conditions. use "if() elseif () else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format your numeric value to a 0-prefixed string.

In your case, `sprintf("%02d", $boptionStrength);`. `%` means there will be a conversion. `0` means the conversion will use this character for padding. `2` means there will be at most 2 padded characters. `d` is for decimal.

```
echo sprintf("%02d", 0);    //outputs 00
echo sprintf("%02d", null); //outputs 00
echo sprintf("%02d", 3);    //outputs 03
echo sprintf("%02d", 42);   //outputs 42
echo sprintf("%02d", 123);  //outputs 123
```

In example, using your function :

```
function liquidBox($boptionStrength)
{
    $boptionStrength = sprintf("%02d", $boptionStrength);
    if ($row["boption$boptionStrength"] >= 1)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have managed it thanks to the hints from Cid (sprintf) and Rishat ($row, boptionStrength)

This is my end result

```
function liquidBox($row, $boptionStrength, $phtext) 
{
$boptionStrength = sprintf("%02d", $boptionStrength);
if ($row["boption$boptionStrength"] >= 1) 
 /*var_dump($boptionStrength); */

{echo "
    <input 
    name='orderdetails[" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "]' 
    id='" . $row['prod_selectname'] . $boptionStrength . "'
    placeholder='$phtext' 
    type='number' 
    class='liq$boptionStrength form-control'" . (($row["boption$boptionStrength"] == 2)?'disabled':"") . "/>";}

}
```

and I am using the following to call the function

```
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 00, '0mg'); ?></td>
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 03, '3mg'); ?></td>
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 06, '6mg'); ?></td>
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 12, '12mg'); ?></td>
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 18, '18mg'); ?></td>
        <td><?php liquidBox($row, 20, '20mg'); ?></td>
```

Thanks for your help